# QPixmap only works with absolute Path

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I am trying to set icons for my `QPushButtons`. I was only able to do so by putting the full path into the `QPixmap` constructor.

Something like this works:

```
m_button->setIcon(QPixmap("C:/Users/Desktop/project/img/pic.png"));
```

So I think the problem does not come from the resource files. However, putting the image into my root directory does not display anything.

So this didn't work:

```
m_button->setIcon(QPixmap("./dog.png"));
```

I initially wanted to create an image folder inside my project but that didn't work either.

```
m_button->setIcon(QPixmap("./img/dog.png"));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add  [Qt-Resource-File](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html) to your application, add the image into it, and the call it like this:

```
QPixmap(":/img/dog.png");
```